# error name not identified in python

Tags: python

Im creating some code where i can sort data into different categories for example sorting the data into alphabetical order. I have the scores from a test stored in 3 different txt files and i need to read them then print it into the order. However in my code it says that the name class_ is not defined. Any help?

```
loop = 1

while loop ==1:
    print("Welcome, you can sort the data from the scores by...")
    print("The following...")
    print()
    print("Option 1) sort score by alphabetically")
    print("Option 2) sort by average score- high to low")
    print("Option 3) sort by highest score- high to low")
    print("Option 5) Exit")

    choice = input("Select your option: ")
    choice = int(choice)



    if choice ==1:
        print("option 1 selected... Alphabetically")


        class_name = input('Which class?:')
        class_name = int(class_)

        if class_==1:
            open('class_1', 'r')
            lineList = inputFile.readlines()
            lineList.sort()
            print('The input in alphabetical order below :')
            for line in  lineList:
                print(line)
```

Comment: Is it possible that you mean `class_ = int(class_name)` instead of `class_name = int(class_)`  ?

Comment: or `if class_==1` is this meant to be `if class_name==1`

Comment: @mike I rolled back your edit to put the code back in, so your question and the answer actually makes sense. Please don't just remove the code from the question when it's been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
class_name = input('Which class?:')
class_name = int(class_)
```

To be

```
class_name = int(input('Which class?:'))
```

And then use `if class_name==1:`

Comment: also it is giving me an error saying that    lineList = inputFile.readlines()  is not defined

Comment: that inputFile is not defined

Comment: Yes, you have to specify the value of `inputFile`

Comment: @mike, well, it's your choice. You're writing this code, so you have to know. For example, `inputFile=open(some_file,"r")`